# Identificar pendrive

Tags: c#, .net, api

Preciso que a aplicação copie um arquivo quando um *pendrive* é conectado. Tem como identificar quando o disco removível é conectado e o nome do volume, para que o sistema não copie para o *pendrive* errado?

Comment: Você pode verificar se o *pendrive* está conectado ou a aplicação precisa ser notificada que houve a conexão? Eu entendi que seria o segundo caso, estou certo?

Comment: A aplicação tinha que ser notificada. Basicamente é assim. É um sistema de backup, ai chegou em uma hora especifica, ele pede pra conectar o pen drive, quando conecta ele copia.

Comment: Ou eu poderia criar um timer que rode de segundo em segundo, até que identifique que o disco foi conectado

Comment: Poderia, mas é uma solução ruim. Vou tentar responder.

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta, apenas uma observação: pendrive é uma das mídias menos confiáveis para se fazer backup. A hora que você percebe que ele deu problema e está devolvendo dados corrompidos, já é tarde.

Comment: Eu sei desse problema, esse é apenas um backup temporário. Ele copia os dados par media removível e ao mesmo tempo para um servidor. Mas obrigado pela observação.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Não é uma tarefa trivial por isto fica difícil colocar uma solução completa aqui no *site*. O caminho é usar a API do Windows para construir um mecanismo de detecção. Achei alguns exemplos na internet. O que me pareceu mais promissor é este [projeto completo no CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program).

Não estou garantindo que vai funcionar para o seu caso e que não precise fazer modificações mas a descrição do projeto que já vi diversas recomendações indica que supre as necessidades que você descreveu. O que eu puder ver é que ele realmente fica esperando que o Windows o notifique através do método `WndProc` que é o padrão do Windows para troca de mensagens. E os parâmetros utilizados, especialmente da mensagem [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), são consistentes com o que se propõe.

Pelo que percebi está fácil customizar com o que precisa e tem um bom exemplo.

Para pegar o volume basta usar pegar a propriedade [`DriveInfo.VolumeLabel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.volumelabel?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_DriveInfo_VolumeLabel):

```
foreach (var d in DriveInfo.GetDrives()) {
    if (d.IsReady) WriteLine($"Volume label: {d.VolumeLabel}");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetDrives.cs).

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma estudada aqui, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma pesquisa e encontrei esse código, ele vai jogar na variável drivers, todos os drivers do tipo removível que estão foram conectados.

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    .Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);
```

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003822/how-to-detect-a-usb-drive-has-been-plugged-in

Comment: Isto detecta a presença ou apenas verifica sob demanda se existe um dispositivo conectado?

Comment: Lista os que estiverem conectados na hora que rodar esse código